# how to mask color channels in java?

Tags: java, colors, mask

I'm trying to write a code that masks red and blue channel from the image inputed. I have retrieved R, G, B values but however stuck up in proceeding further. Can anyone help me in this please?

```
public class Green {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));

        for (int x = 0; x <= bi.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y <= bi.getHeight(); y++) {
                int pixelCol = bi.getRGB(x, y);
                int r = (pixelCol >> 16) & 0xff;
                int b = pixelCol & 0xff;
                int g = (pixelCol >> 8) & 0xff;
                int px = 0;
                px = (px | (g << 8));
                bi.setRGB(x, y, px);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use in the IDE code formatting. Usually it is accessible using Ctrl-Shift-F or Cmd-Shift-F for OSX users.

Comment: In your for loop, you shouldn't use `<=` but `<`. Example: when you have 4 elements, they have an index 0, 1, 2, 3.

Comment: And what is the question? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Note that this line is invalid: `px=(px|(g<<8);` - there's at least one paranthesis missing (in `ImageIO.read(new File( "image.jpg" )` too). You also could write it as `px |= g << 8;` btw. As Martijn already said, formatting your code would help a lot in reading it and finding bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Some remarks:

- Use an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) like Eclipse or NetBeans.
- Use `<` instead of `<=` as condition in your for loops.
- Use code formatting (that is a feature of the IDE)
- For clearness, order `r`, `g` and `b`.

  ```
  int r = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
  int g = (color >> 8) & 0xff;
  int b = (color >> 0) & 0xff;
  ```
- Since you said you were stuck, the only thing left to do is save the manipulated image:

  ```
  ImageIO.write(bi, "JPG", new File("green.jpg"));
  ```
- A little trick to perform the mask quickly is this:

  ```
  bi.setRGB(x, y, bi.getRGB(x, y) & 0xff00ff00);
  ```

---

So, the clean working code should be this:

```
public class Green
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {     
        /* Read the image */
        BufferedImage bi= ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));   

        /* Loop through all the pixels */   
        for (int x=0; x < bi.getWidth(); x++)
        {          
            for (int y = 0; y < bi.getHeight(); y++)
            {   
                /* Apply the green mask */                      
                bi.setRGB(x, y, bi.getRGB(x, y) & 0xff00ff00);
            }
        }

        /* Save the image */
        ImageIO.write(bi, "JPG", new File("green_mask.jpg"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to copying and scaling images, the Java 2D API also filter an image. Filtering is drawing or producing a new image by applying an algorithm to the pixels of the source image.

Image filters can be applied by using the following method:

```
void Graphics2D.drawImage(BufferedImage img,
                      BufferedImageOp op,
                      int x, int y)
```

The **BufferedImageOp** parameter implements the filter.

See this document for Image filter examples: http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780132413930/samplechapter/0132413930_CH08.pdf